# Running node.js from Maven?

Tags: node.js, maven

I'd like to run a node.js application from Maven (https://github.com/mdevils/node-jscs in particular), and if any errors are found then print them to the console and break the build.

Are there any well-maintained Maven plugins that integrate with node.js in this way?